# Fuzzy Timer (random within boundaries) (Arduino)

Tags: c++, random, timer, arduino

I need a little help trying to make a timer a little fuzzy.  I want to use a fixed interval of timing like this:

```
____|_______|____|_____|_________|_____|___|_______|
```

where the pipe is the event occurrence and the underscore is the delay in an array like this:

```
int myIntervals = { 1000, 2000, 750, 850, 1200, 850, 500, 1000};
```

but the values are arbitrary.

I would like to create a slight randomness to the event, but not allow the randomness to affect the overall timing:

```
___*|*_____*|*__*|*___*|*_______*|*___*|*_*|*_____*|
```

where the randomness is described as the time contained by asterisks.

So the event always happens at the interval +- a random delay:

int fuzzyPeriod = random(-75, 75);

I've experimented around this but to no avail... I'm finding myself in a recursion when the fuzzy period is negative, or like this I get a millis() overflow problem, obviously.

```
int sequence[] = {1000, 750, 950, 1150, 1200, 1500, 1000, 1900, 2000};
unsigned int index;
unsigned long startMillis = 0;
unsigned int fuzzy = sequence[0];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (startMillis < millis())  // will have rollover issues <<<<<<<
  {
    if (millis() - startMillis >= fuzzy)
    {
      digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
      startMillis += sequence[index];   // advance startMillis by the last interval used
      index++;
      if (index >= sizeof(sequence) / sizeof(sequence[0]))
      {
        index = 0;
        Serial.println("Restarted Sequence");
      }
      fuzzy = sequence[index] + random(-75, 76); // arbitrary offset needs to be positive or negative
      Serial.print("fuzzy = ");
      Serial.println(fuzzy);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I've done a good job explaining... I cannot for the life of me get this done and I know I'm to the point where I need a little help!

Comment: I dont know anything about the arduino, but it might help to store the absolut timing values. E.g. instead of your {1000,750,950,...} store {1000,1750,2700,...}. Then randomize those (except for the last one probably) and calculate the differences as sequence[index]-sequence[index-1].

Comment: I considered that, but the data size has to be larger,  The MCU has very little storage capability.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
unsigned int index;
unsigned long nextMillis;
int prevFuzzy = 0;
int fuzzy = 0;

void setup()
{
    //...
    nextMillis = millis();
}

void loop()
{
    if (millis() >= nextMillis)
    {
        fuzzy = random(-75, 76);
        // compensate for previous deviation and add new one
        nextMillis += sequence[index] - prevFuzzy + fuzzy;
        fuzzy = prevFuzzy;

        // or just:
        // fuzzy = random(-75, 76) - fuzzy
        // nextMillis += sequence[index] + fuzzy;

        index++;
        if (index >= sizeof(sequence) / sizeof(sequence[0]))
        {
            index = 0;
        }

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, won't do it, the timing can cascade out of sync.

`nextMillis += sequence[index] + random(-75, 76);`

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton I knew you'd write this! See the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use unsigned long for milliseconds to properly account for the overflow.

Then I also initialized the variables at different places and startMillis with a different value

```
int sequence[] = {1000, 750, 950, 1150, 1200, 1500, 1000, 1900, 2000};
unsigned int index = 0;
unsigned long startMillis;
unsigned int fuzzy = sequence[0] + random(-75, 76);

#include <limits.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  startMillis = millis();
}

void loop()
{
  long MilliDiff;
  if (startMillis <= millis())
    MilliDiff = millis() - startMillis;
  else
    MilliDiff = ULONG_MAX - startMillis + millis();

  if (MilliDiff >= fuzzy)
    {
      digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
      startMillis += sequence[index];   // advance startMillis by the last interval used

      index++;
      if (index >= sizeof(sequence) / sizeof(sequence[0]))
      {
        index = 0;
        Serial.println("Restarted Sequence");
      }

      fuzzy = sequence[index] + random(-75, 76); // arbitrary offset needs to be positive or negative
      Serial.print("startMillis = ");
      Serial.print(startMillis);
      Serial.print(",  sequence = ");
      Serial.print(sequence[index]);
      Serial.print(",  fuzzy = ");
      Serial.println(fuzzy);
    }
}
```

This code seems to be working on my Uno